# Custom Infowindow Google Maps Android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

É possível customizar uma InfoWindow do marcador no GoogleMaps v2 do Android, colocando botões clicáveis, imagens, alterar a cor do background etc?

Se sim, como posso fazer isso? Agradeço se alguém tiver um tutorial sobre o assunto

Answer (score 1):

E possível sim, existe esse tutorial [Markers e Listeners Google Maps](http://www.thiengo.com.br/markers-e-listeners-no-google-maps-android) que explica super bem como fazer e segue abaixo um exemplo.

```
map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter(){

@Override
public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
    ll.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
    ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

    TextView tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b><font color=\"#ffffff\">"+marker.getTitle()+":</font></b> "+marker.getSnippet()));
    ll.addView(tv);

    Button bt = new Button(MainActivity.this);
    bt.setText("Botão");
    bt.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("Script", "Botão clicado");
        }

    });

    ll.addView(bt);

    return ll;
}
```

});